# Why do i still have swaps when quick sort is run on a sorted list?

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

When I run this quick sort on an array of 10 integers that i have already put in order there are still 20 swaps and I cant figure out why that is.

```
public int partition(int array[], int low, int high) 
    { 
        int pivot = array[(low+high)/2];  
        int i = (low-1); 
        for (int j = low; j < high; j++) 
        {
            compCounter++;
            if (array[j] <= pivot) 
            { 
                i++; 
                int temp = array[i]; 
                array[i] = array[j]; 
                array[j] = temp; 
                SwapCounter++;
            } 
        } 

        int temp = array[i+1]; 
        array[i+1] = array[high]; 
        array[high] = temp; 
        SwapCounter++;

        return i+1; 
    } 

    public void quickSort(int array[], int low, int high) 
    { 
        if (low < high) 
        { 
            int pivotPoint = partition(array, low, high); 
            quickSort(array, low, pivotPoint-1); 
            quickSort(array, pivotPoint+1, high); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Because quicksort is notoriously bad on sorted lists.

Comment: The code appears to be a partially modified Lomuto scheme where the pivot was changed from array[high] to the middle value array[(low+high)/2], but it's still always swapping array[i+1] with array[high], which is normally used to put the pivot value into it's proper location. Usually the if is `array[j] < pivot`. Take a look at Wiki for [Lomuto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) and [Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). Hoare scheme may be better for using middle value as pivot.